# copying arrays in javascript/p5js turning all values into 0s?

Tags: javascript, arrays, processing, fft, p5.js

I have this simple code, Im trying to keep an array of arrays , which is just the FFT audio data. I think this is a javascript issue, but Im not sure what is wrong.  fft.analyze() just returns an array of numbers. after I push the array into the array spectrums, all the values inside of spectrums are 0s instead of the actual values. Using array.splice(0) is supposed to be a deep copy.  Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong here?

```
var fft,mic;
function setup(){
  var myCanvas = createCanvas(800,800); 
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  ellipse(400,400,50,50)
  colorMode(HSB,100)
  spectrums=[]
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  fft.setInput(mic);
}

function draw() {
  background(255)
  s = fft.analyze(16)
 for(si=0;si<s.length;si++){
   fill(s[si]%100,100,100)
  rect(si*10,0,si*10,s[si]) 
 }
 spectrums.push(s.splice(0))
  if(spectrums.length > 5){
    spectrums.splice(-1,1)
  }
  console.log(spectrums[0][0]) //this prints 0 always
for(si=0;si<spectrums[0].length;si++){
   fill(spectrums[0][si]%100,100,100)
  rect(si*10,400,si*10,spectrums[0][si]) 
 }
}
```

Comment: If you want to turn all values of an array to zero you could do arr.map(c=>0)

Comment: You'll have better luck if you post a [mcve] instead of this code, which depends on hardware input and makes it very hard to run. Try creating a small example program that just uses hardcoded arrays to show exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: `splice` != `slice`

Comment: This code is runnable, here is a full link of it running: https://www.pushpopchallenge.com/submissions/23  it should have 2 of those graphs appearing, but only 1 does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault.  The problem was using unshift instead of pop.
The first array it gets is full of 0s.
Here you can see what I was trying to make: https://www.pushpopchallenge.com/submissions/22

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=control)

and not 
[splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control)

So where you're doing

```
spectrums.push(s.splice(0))
```

`s` gets emptied from the start (**0** index)

What you want to do is

```
spectrums.push(s.slice(0))
```

`slice()` leaves the original array untouched and just creates a copy.

`splice()` on the other hand just modifies the original array by inserting or deleting elements.

Comment: I just tried with slice(), I get the exact same issues. I had previously tried with many different copy mechanisms such as JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray))    but nothing works. Im at a loss as to what to do.

Comment: and im sure  fft.analyze() returns a normal array: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/lib/addons/p5.sound.js#L2708   im sure its a javascript problem, but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Makes no sense... after and before `slice` you `s` array should still be full of data.